# R the size of my graph is twice as big on linux than it is on windows

Tags: linux, r, windows, ggplot2

I have a strange problem with my stacked plots, which must be outputted as .png. I have R 3.1.3 on windows xp and on linux mint ( linux is my guest OS via virtual box , with my host windows xp). I have no other problem with my linux, besides the natural sluggishness of such a set-up. I must use linux because of the better management of the locales; windows renders all my characters from various alphabets all gibberish, despite the language pack installed.

The sizes of my graphs on linux (mint 17.1) are twice the ones on windows. Does this come from the fact that my linux is used via virtual box ?
I have no particular reason to install linux, that's why I have put it in a box. I have this little message when I log in on my linux through virtual box:

[image]

Can you tell me what sizes are the graphs on your system ?

the result in terms of sizes, see the GSC graphs

```
windowsGridnoGROBnoLOESS.png is 98 kB
windowsGridyesGROBnoLOESS.png is 679kB
windowsgscGROBnoLOESS.png is 332 kB
windowsGscnoGROBnoLOESS.png is 49 kB
windowsGscnoGROByesLOESS is 49 kB
windowsgscyesGROByesLOESS.png is 340 kB

linuxGridnoGROBnoLOESS is 104kB
linuxGridyesGROBnoLOESS is 729 kB
linuxgscGROBnoLOESS is 334 kB
linuxGscnoGROBnoLOESS is 48 kB
linuxGscnoGROByesLOESS is 115kB
linuxgscyesGROByesLOESS is 805 kB
```

especially once I incorporate the loess data, the size increases on linux but less on windows.

My personal graphs weight around 700KB on windows and nearly 3 MB on linux ! My graphs are closer to the graphs `gsc` since they have a long legend and are colored, with alpha layers and many many points with also the loess smoothings.

The basic graph can reproduce the phenomenon:
if you do not comment the first graph, you will need to download the data
[here](http://zevross.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/chicago-nmmaps.csv)

I have put the `arial` font to avoid size discrepancies, but I think it is unnecessary. Feel free to comment the lines about the `extrafonts` and the line for the `gsc` plot theme.

```
require("ggplot2")
require("grid")
require("gridExtra")
require("extrafont")
# font_import() # import all your fonts
# fonts() #get a list of fonts
loadfonts(device = "win")


nmmaps<-read.csv("chicago-nmmaps.csv", as.is=T)

g<-ggplot(nmmaps, aes(date, temp, color=o3))+geom_point()

png(filename = "linuxGridnoGROBnoLOESS.png", width = 1920, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 67.5)
g
dev.off()

png(filename = "linuxGridyesGROBnoLOESS.png", width = 1920, height = 4200, units = "px", pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 67.5)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(g,g,g,g,g,g,g,ncol=1, nrow=7))
dev.off()

gsc<- ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price, color=cut), data = diamonds) + geom_point()+
  theme_grey(base_family = "Arial") + theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey95", colour=NA))

png(filename = "linuxGscnoGROBnoLOESS.png", width = 1920, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 67.5)
gsc
dev.off()


png(filename = "linuxgscGROBnoLOESS.png", width = 1920, height = 4200, units = "px", pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 67.5)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(gsc,gsc,gsc,gsc,gsc,gsc,gsc,ncol=1, nrow=7))
dev.off()



gscloess<- ggplot(aes(x = carat, y = price, color=cut), data = diamonds) + geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(method="loess", aes(group = 1), se=FALSE, span = 0.2, size=1.25, n=200, fullrange = T)+
  theme_grey(base_family = "Arial") + theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="grey95", colour=NA))

png(filename = "linuxGscnoGROByesLOESS.png", width = 1920, height = 600, units = "px", pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 67.5)
gscloess
dev.off()

png(filename = "linuxgscyesGROByesLOESS.png", width = 1920, height = 4200, units = "px", pointsize = 11, bg = "white",  res = 67.5)
grid.arrange(arrangeGrob(gscloess,gscloess,gscloess,gscloess,gscloess,gscloess,gscloess,ncol=1, nrow=7))
dev.off()
```

Comment: The documentation of `png` gives some details (on my win7 machine with R 3.1.2) regarding pallettes that might be relevant.

Comment: all the png files with grob are in 24 bit for iwndows and linux; they are in 8 bit., on linux and windows, when grob is not used.

Comment: Linux is at least twice better value

Comment: can somebody copy and paste the code to  compile it and give the size of the files ?

Answer (score 0):

I used `optipng` to reduce the size of the outputs from linux, but they remain higher than the ones on windows.

I also had to install `xfonts-100-dpi` and everything works, but the output is very ugly. but also very light.